# How can I mention this user?

Tags: support, display-names, comment-replies

I just stumbled upon this user: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260841/%e1%94%95%e1%96%ba%e1%98%8e%e1%95%8a

His nickname is probably some emoji which my browser is unable to detect. How to mention such users?

Comment: Are you asking about comment threads in which they've already posted, a chat room in which they're present, or something else?

Comment: I'm a bit of a pain really... :P